# Factory for abstract class

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class `MyAbstractClass`.

I also have lots of implementations of that class, and I want to create a factory for these implementations.

Need to end up with usage like that: `MyAbstractClass.Factory.CreateSomething();`

Now I don't know which style I should use:

1) `Factory` should be nested static class with static methods
2) `Factory` should be static property which returns instance of `FactoryClass`
   ... a) (will not work) //`FactoryClass` have static methods, and public or internal constructor
   ... b) `FactoryClass` have instance methods, and public or internal constructor

What do you think?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29 - not sure if last one is compatible with static factories.

Answer (score 1):

> Need to end up with usage like that: `MyAbstractClass.Factory.CreateSomething();`

Why? Syntax is largely irrelevant compared to the semantics of the design. This for example makes it more difficult to use different instance of the factory in different places. In other words, it's a coupling issue. Maybe it's a good place to introduce coupling (since it is not meaningful to instantiate these classes other ways) but probably not.

If you do *really* want this, then don't get fancy. Just have a static readonly instance of Factory on the abstract class. This allows you to make the factory class just another class. It makes it easy to use elsewhere. It makes it easy to test.

Simple is good.

Comment: I don't need to test Factory class, and use it somewhere else. What's is better: var silence = WaveData.Factory.Silence (numSamples, sampleRate); or var silence = new WaveDataConstant (0, numSamples, samplerate); ?

Comment: @zgnilec - you _do_ need to test your code. Seriously. And the syntax depends on the implementation. If you're making a new object, the latter is less surprising, but in the long run, these sorts of syntactic minutiae don't matter.

Comment: I have tests for implementations that returns Factory. For example, in Linq you use chaining and not make code like that: var oldPersons = new LinqFilter (persons, x => x.Age > 50); which returns some class with IEnumerable interface. So i think that factory will be good.

Comment: @zgnilec - you know that Linq doesn't use factories, right?

Comment: I know, but the syntax is clean. What about Task.factory.StartNew?